# Custom FTP application: representing status and error codes

Tags: java, oop

Let's say I want to write an FTP client from scratch. In the command channel various status and error codes can be passed between server and client such as :

- 200   Command okay
- 331   User name okay, need password
- 421   Service not available
- ...

Ideally, the numeric code and a human-readable message should be kept.

How should these be represented ? As an enum in some sort of `Connection` class ? What could be done to accomodate different messages or new codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the enums with some logic contains:

```
public enum FTPReturnCode {
     OKAY(200), NAME_OK_PW_NEEDED(331), ... ;
}
```

Since the FTP doesn't change since 1985 (rfc959), you can add all FTP response codes into the enum class.

Comment: Ok, so constants will leave a programmer free to use the text message they want. "Since the FTP doesn't change since 1985 (rfc959)" What would you do if this actually changed or if another, newer, standard is involved ? Keep an enum and extend/override via settings loaded from a configuration file ?

Comment: You probably then release a new version of your software, since the protocol changes. Basically, you can't protect your code 100% from changing world.